# Will ARCore be implementing Tango level ToF capability or will Tango be relaunched to support new phones with ToF?

Tags: arcore

With new phones (Huawei P30 Pro, Oppo RX17 Pro, Galaxy S10,etc) now having rear ToF, will Google relaunch Tango or build the ToF (structured light) capabilities into ARCore. I used Tango to develop for the Asus Zenfone AR and loved what you could do with it, but Tango was shelved soon afterwards. With rear ToF coming back around (and hopefully hear to stay), when will Google re-release their ToF SDK so to be able to develop for ToF again?

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting question. Two years ago, Google might feel disappointed that few manufacturers were willing to integrate depth camera. However today, the trend seems to that more and more high-end phones are going to integrate structure light for front-face camera and ToF for rear-face camera. First because of the hard competition among Android phones, second, rumors says the next generation iPhone will do so as well. As long as the hardware manufactures are willing to integrate it, there is no reason for Google NOT to relaunch Tango, or let's say re-enable those Tango feature in the next version of ARCore.